# How to see a variable's value in an array when program is running in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, variables

I was doing program in Xcode 4 and I can't see values of the variables. I have activated breakpoints but the problem is that Xcode displays only varibles which are raw. For example

```
int i,j,k
```

It displays all these values but I don't know how to do this for arrays.As for example

```
int arr[10],i
```

I want the value of arr[i] at specific time.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the array just like any other variable.

[image: viewing arrays in Xcode 4's debugger]

If by 'string' you mean an `std::string`, unfortunately Xcode 4 still doesn't have great support for viewing C++ standard library types. You can do it like this though:

[image: viewing std::string in LLDB]

If you mean `char const *` you can view them as easily as any array.

[image: char* in Xcode 4's debugger]

Comment: what in case of string? i am stuck in strings